# Select and use part of an AWS s3 object key using Ruby aws-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to list only the objects from the s3 folder (not a real folder I know) called `distribution` but I want to remove the reference to the name and any slashes around the object. The output should just look like `021498cd-ca73-4675-a57a-c12b3c652aac` whereas currently it looks like `distribution/021498cd-ca73-4675-a57a-c12b3c652aac/`

So far I have tried;

```
def files
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new


    s3.client
    bucket = s3.bucket('test')
    files = []

    bucket.objects.each do |obj|
     if obj.key.include?('distribution/')
      temp_files = puts "#{obj.key}"
      files = temp_files.select do |file|
        file.gsub("distribution/", "")
      end
    else
    end
 end
end
```

But this doesn't seem to be working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is pretty simple but your code is implying something else.

However, this should help with what you are trying to achieve.

```
def files
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

  s3.client
  bucket = s3.bucket('test')
  files = []

  bucket.objects.each do |obj|
    if obj.key.include?('distribution/')
      files << "#{file.gsub(/(distribution)|\//, '')}"
    end   
  end
end
```

The `files` array will contain all the file names with garbage stripped.